# Is sum of non-negative closed sets closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Sum of two closed sets $A,B$ is closed is not necessarily closed. Every answer I could find constructs a counterexample exploiting **subtraction** in some way, the easiest one being
$$
A=\mathbb Z_{\ge1},\;B=\left\{-n+\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge2}\right\}\\
0\notin A+B
$$
A hard one is
$$
A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y > 1/x,x > 0\},\; B = \{(x, y) \in\mathbb R^2 : y > -1/x,x < 0\}\\
\mathbb R\times\{0\}\not\subset  A+B = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y > 0\}
$$
Another one uses a density argument
$$
A=\mathbb Z,\;B=\alpha\mathbb Z\quad(\alpha\in\mathbb{ R\setminus Q})\\
\mathbb R\not\subseteq A+B
$$
Even the last one uses subtraction to achieve density. Replacing $\mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb N$ in the last counterexample does not work.

> Q: $A,B$ are closed subsets of $[0,\infty)$. Must $A+B$ be closed?

Restriction to non-negative numbers takes away the possibility of exploiting subtraction in some sense so I think the answer is **yes**. Picking a Cauchy sequence $\{c_n\}$ in $A+B$ we see $$\exists (a_n,b_n)\in A\times B: a_n+b_n=c_n$$ Assuming $c_n\to c>0$ we note that $\exists N:$ if $n> N$,
$$ a_n+b_n\in B\left(c,\frac{c}{2}\right)\implies \frac{c}{2}<a_n+b_n<\frac{3c}{2}\implies \frac{c}{2}<a_n,b_n<\frac{3c}{2}$$
$\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ are bounded sequences and by Bolzano Weierstrass each has at least one limit point but I can't continue from here on.

If however $c=0$, it is clear that $a_n,b_n\to 0$ and therefore $0\in A+B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $A,B$ are closed subsets of $[0,\infty)$.

Suppose $a_n + b_n \to c$, then we must have $a_n,b_n$ are bounded 
(since $a_n \le a_n + b_n$), and similarly for $b_n$) and
so there is some $(a,b)$ and some subsequence such that $(a_{n_k},b_{n_k}) \to (a,b)$.

Since $A,B$ are closed, $a\in A, b \in B$ and
since $a_{n_k}+b_{n_k} \to c$ we have $c=a+b$, hence $A+B$ is closed.

Comment: Are we applying Bolzano-Weierstrass in $\mathbb R^2$ here to conclude $\exists$ a subsequence converging to $(a,b)$ ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$